# Data anonymization using python

Tags: python

I have an unstructured, free form text (taken from emails, phone conversation transcriptions), a list of first names and a  list of last names.
What would be the most effective and pythonistic method to replace all the first names in the text with "--FIRSTNAME--" and last names with "--LASTNAME--" based on the lists I have?
I could iterate over each of the first name list and do a
text.replace(firstname, '--FIRSTNAME--')
but that seems very inefficient, especially for a very long list of names and many long texts to process. Are there better options?

Example:

- Text: "Hello, this is David, how may I help you? Hi, my name is Alex Bender and I am trying to install my new coffee machine."
- First name list: ['Abe', 'Alex', 'Andy', 'David', 'Mark', 'Timothy']
- Last name list: ['Baxter', Bender', 'King', McLoud']

Expected output: "Hello, this is --FIRSTNAME--, how may I help you? Hi, my name is --FIRSTNAME-- --LASTNAME-- and I am trying to install my new coffee machine."

Comment: This depends on your data structure. Is it a pandas table? A list? Can you provide example data?

Comment: As I specified, unstructured. This is free text

Comment: if you could get word by word then you could check it in `set()` with names and checking in `set()` should be faster - `if word in set(names):`. My could also split text on smaller parts and send to subprocess to run them at the same time. Or you should check in Google if there are modules for this - maybe they will work faster. Maybe [FlashText](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/11/flashtext-a-library-faster-than-regular-expressions/) ?

Comment: @furas FlashText is exactly what I needed! You hit the nail on the head. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of @furas and checked out the flashtext module. This pretty much answers my need to the fullest.
I did run into a problem as I am working with Hebrew (non ASCII characters) and the text replacement would not follow word boundaries.
There is a method (add_non_word_boundary(self, character)) of class KeywordProcessor, which for some reason is not documented, that allows to add characters which are not to be considered as boundary characters (in addition to the default [a-zA-Z0-9_], allowing for whole word replacement only.